# In this code, what is the purpose of the values 1.0/255 and (0,0,0)?

Tags: python, opencv

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of values `1.0 / 255` and `(0, 0, 0)` here?

```py
inpBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0 / 255, (inWidth, inHeight),
                                    (0, 0, 0), swapRB=False, crop=False)
```

Comment: Did you [check the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga0b7b7c3c530b747ef738178835e1e70f)? What is unclear from the docs?

Comment: Hey, so I will try to guide you to not get so many minus points in the future. "Someone plz guide me " should be removed. The question should be general and neutral. The community is very harsh if you not show already established work, like "I go trough the docs and still need a suport". Make a bullet points to nicely separate many questions. Be strong and not do not perceive these negative points as something wrong. With every next question you will be better and better.

Answer (score 2):

It is a scalefactor, https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html.

`scalefactor - multiplier for image values.`

as RBG are from 0 to 255 so when each of the value is multiplied by the 1/255 , we will get a representation from 0 to 1. Often made to get a grey representation.

(0,0,0) is a mean argument. Here you do not subtract any value from RGB channels, because of only zeros.

`mean - scalar with mean values which are subtracted from channels. Values are intended to be in (mean-R, mean-G, mean-B) order if image has BGR ordering and swapRB is true.`